# Number pattern in C

Tags: c, logic

Can you please help to print the below pattern?

```
 12345 15
  2345   14
   345     12
    45        9
     5          5
```

I have tried with this code?

code :

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for(j=i;j<=5;j++)
        {
            printf("%i",j);
            sum = sum + j;
        }

        printf(" ");
        printf("%i",sum);
        printf("\n");
    }
```

output:

```
 12345 15
  2345 29
   345 41
    45 50
     5 55
```

Please help to print the above pattern? Thanks in advance

Comment: What problems are you having exactly? Where does the outcome differ from your expectation?

Comment: Edit the output you are getting directly into the question. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: @RedX Please see the edited question and help me if you know.

Comment: @Parthiban  Please see my answer I have added the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the problem is clear: 29 = 15 + 14.

This means you are forgetting to clear sum when you begin a new line.

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
    sum = 0; // reset sum when we begin a new line
```

Answer (score 1):

First problem with logic is that -

```
for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
{
        sum=0;   // set sum to 0 in every iteration
```

You don't do this , therefore you don't get right sum and you get this -

```
  15+14=29
  29+12=41  // similar for all cases
```

[Solution](https://ideone.com/JElu5T) -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
     int i,j,sum=0,k=1;
     char p[10];                  // using a char array to print spaces between number ans sun
     memset(p,'\0',sizeof p);     // initialize array elements to null
    for(i=1;i<=5;i++)
     {  
        sum =0;                     // set sum to 0 in every iteration 
        for(j=1;j<=i;j++)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }

       for(j=i;j<=5;j++)
       {
           printf("%i",j);   
           sum = sum + j;
       }
       if(k<10){                    // this is to print space between number and sum 
          memset(p,' ',k);         // include number of space in string 
          printf("%s",p);          // print the string with space
       }
        k=k+2;                         // increment k by 2
        printf("%i",sum);
        printf("\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```